# factoring a linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $E_{1} , E_{2} , E_{3}$ are three vector spaces , and $f : E_{1} \to E_{3}$ and $g : E_{1} \to E_{2}$ are linear mappings , if we have $ Ker(g) \subseteq Ker(f) $ how to prove that $f$ factor through $g$ , that is how to prove the existence of another linear mapping $h : E_{2} \to E_{3}$ such that $f = h \circ g $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider a basis $U=(u_1,\ldots,u_k)$ of $g(E_1)$ and let $\bar U=(u_1,\ldots,u_k,v_1,\ldots,v_j)$ its extension to a basis of $E_2$.

We can now define $h:E_2\to E_3$ on the elements of $\bar U$:

$$h(u_i)=f(x)\ \text{for any }x\in g^{-1}(u_i) \ \ \  1\le i\le k$$
$$h(v_i)=0\ \ \ \ \  1\le i\le j$$

We only have to show that $g(a)=g(b) \iff g(a-b)=0 \Rightarrow f(a-b)=0 \iff f(a)=f(b)$, but that follows from $\ker(g)\subset \ker(f)$